# How can I get resistance from temperature?

Tags: c++, arduino, arduino-uno

I have a value in temperature and I want to get a resistance value from this temperature.

I use [Steinhart-Hart method](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steinhart%E2%80%93Hart_equation) but this equation always returns 7,39 regardless of temperatures and coefficients.

My second implementation based on steinhart method (see below) doesn't work with negative coefficients.

Do you know what's the problem with my code ?

```
double WSensor::temperatureToResistance(double _temp)
{
    double Temp = _temp + 273.15;
    double X = ((this->therm->getA() - (1 / Temp)) / this->therm->getC());
    double Y = this->therm->getB() / this->therm->getC();
    double argExpo = pow(-(X / 2) + pow((X*X) / 4 + (Y*Y*Y) / 27, 1.0 / 2.), 1.0 / 3.0) - pow((-(X / 2) - pow((X*X) / 4 + (Y*Y*Y) / 27, 1.0 / 2.0)) * (-1), 1.0 / 3.0); 

    return exp(argExpo);
}
```

Comment: Your code matches with the equations up to the calculation of `X`, and a little bit of the calculation of `Y`, and then it just goes in a completely different direction, nothing matches up.

Comment: @hobbs, just my thoughts. Due to the difference in `y` it could be right. But if I was OP, I'd implement it exactly the same way first to be on the safe side. Have you tried that, @Mindsers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After 3 days of work, I know why this equation does not work on arduino : overflowing.

Some parts of the equation create `float` too large for this board model (Arduino Uno).

One of the solutions is to rephrase the equation to prevent bigger results. But this solution takes too much time and need good mathematical skills, that's why I decided to move the equation in an external API.

Comment: Are you sure it's related to being a `float`? [Here](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/constants/) it says "The default type for floating-point literals is double. Floating-point literals of type float or long double can be specified by adding one of the following suffixes...". And I can only see floating-point literals and `double`s in your code.

Comment: @AndrasDeak Normally, `float < double < long double` but [here](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/Float) the documentation says "Unlike other platforms, where you can get more precision by using a double (e.g. up to 15 digits), on the Arduino, double is the same size as float.". So, the precision and the capacity of type (int, double, etc) depend on the microcontroller architecture,  arduino microcontroller work on 8-bit...

Comment: Oh, I see, thanks for the clarification. So I'm guessing `long double` won't help you either, since if there was an option to have more bits, then `double` would already have that.

Comment: @AndrasDeak exactly! these are the joys of embedded programming